# How to update/add child posts meta whenever the parent post meta is updated?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

I couldn't find a solution to a very simple problem.

When a meta value for the parent post is updated, I want the meta value of all child posts linked to this parent post to be updated.

For example: I want the "red" meta value to be automatically selected for the child posts when the "red" meta value is selected for the parent post. (for the _post_color meta key) Or if this parent post value updated, value must change automatically in child posts too.

I tried to do it using the code below, but it did not help. I added it to functions.php file.

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_child_posts_meta', 10, 2);
add_action('post_updated', 'change_child_posts_meta', 10, 2);
function change_child_posts_meta($post_id, $post)
{

    if ( $post->post_parent == 0 && 'my_post_type' == $post->post_type) {

        $mettta = get_post_meta( $post->ID , "_post_color" , true );

        $args = array(
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
        $ChildIDs = get_children($args);

        foreach ($ChildIDs as $childID) {
            update_post_meta( $childID, "_post_color", $mettta );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A better hook for what you're trying to do, is [`updated_postmeta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_postmeta/). Just be careful or avoid infinite loop - i.e. "unhook" and "re-hook" where appropriate.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you. I found the cause of the problem. I added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem I was having. Since the post type I was working on was woccommerce orders (shop_order), I had to enter the post status correctly.

The edited code is as follows:

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_child_posts_meta', 10, 2);
add_action('post_updated', 'change_child_posts_meta', 10, 2);

function change_child_posts_meta($post_id, $post)
{

    if ( $post->post_parent == 0 && 'shop_order' == $post->post_type) {

        $mettta = get_post_meta( $post->ID , "_post_color" , true );

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_status' => array('wc-pending','wc-processing','wc-on-hold','wc-completed','wc-cancelled','wc-refunded','wc-failed','wc-shipping-progress')
        );
        $ChildIDs = get_posts( $args );

        foreach ($ChildIDs as $childID) {
            update_post_meta( $childID->ID, "_post_color", $mettta );
        }

    }
}
```